# How to solve the following system?

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-equations, generating-functions, power-series

I need to find the function c(k), knowing that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c(k)}{k!}=1$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c(2k)}{(2k)!}=0$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c(2k+1)}{(2k+1)!}=1$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k c(2k+1)}{(2k+1)!}=-1$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k c(2k)}{(2k)!}=0$$

Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that 0 + -1 = 1?

Comment: Could you tell us a little about your motivation?

Comment: There was a typo, sorry. in the last equation there should be 1

Comment: The $k!$ seems to be a complete red herring - define $b(k) \equiv c(k)/k!$ and the equivalent question is more elegant IMO. Anyway, there are clearly an infinite number of functions that will work (e.g. $c(k_0) = k_{(0)}!$ for any odd $k_0$, with all other $c(k)$'s equal to $0$). e: obviously this no longer applies since your edit.

Comment: I have added some equations and it seems that the first equation is not necessary because it follows from the second and third.

Comment: Is that your final question?

Comment: Yes, if these equations are enough to find the function in question. I believe they are enough.

Comment: @Math: No they aren't enough. There are still infinitely many solutions.

Comment: No, I believe that there is still an infinite number of possible solutions. E.g. $c(2k_0 + 1) = (2k_0 + 1)!$ for some odd $k_0$, with all other $c(k)$ equal to zero.

Comment: @Rotwang: Unless inconsistent, given a finite number of equations like those, there will always be an infinitely many number of solutions, by setting the "tail" of the series to 0 and getting a set of linear equations which have more variables than equations.

Comment: @Moron: Indeed.

Comment: Well obviously this is not enough, this system is satisfied by c(1)=1, otherwise 0 function. I have to add more equations.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a function $\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{c(k)}{k!} z^k$ satisfying

$$f(1) = 1$$
$$f(-1) = -1$$
$$f(i) = -i.$$

Infinitely many functions have this property.  There is a unique quadratic polynomial $p(z)$ with this property (for example by [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)), and for any entire function $q(z)$ the function $p(z) + (x - 1)(x + 1)(x - i) q(z)$ has this property.  In fact these are all entire functions with this property.

More generally I think the theory of interpolation by entire functions is fairly well-understood, but I don't know of a good reference.  If the set of $z$ at which you fix the value of $f$ has a limit point, then $f$ is unique by the identity theorem.  If the set of $z$ at which you fix the value of $f$ is countable and does not have a limit point, then $f$ is non-unique by [Weierstrass factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Following Rotwang, define $b(k)=c(k)/k!$, then note that both the second and fifth can be satisfied as long as $\sum{b(2k)}=0$.  Then the first and third are redundant and define $d(k)=b(2k+1)$.  Now we have $\sum{d(k)}=1, \sum{(-1)^kd(k)}=-1$.  Adding and subtracting, $\sum{d(2k)}=0, \sum{d(2k+1)}=1.$  So the final is that we must have $$\begin{align} \sum\frac{c(2k)}{k!}&=0\\
   \sum\frac{c(4k+1)}{(4k+1)!}&=0\\
   \sum\frac{c(4k+3)}{(4k+3)!}&=1  \end{align}$$

and any $c(k)$ that satisfies this will work.

Comment: @Mike Spivey, Rotwang:  Fixed.  Sorry for that, Rotwang.

Comment: Thank you. Seems the system is too loose.

Comment: @MathFacts:  Yes.  You can think of it as 3 equations and an infinite number of variables.

Comment: @MathFacts:  Making the last more explicit, there is nothing in the problem statement relating the c(k) to each other for different k.